# Is there any general rule when assigning role to gateway in Cloudera Spark2?

Tags: apache-spark, cloudera, gateway

I am planning upgrade the existing Spark 1.6 to 2.1 in Cloudera, I was advised that I should assign gateway role to all Node Manager and Resource Manager nodes. Current gateway role is assigned to a proxy node, which is not included in the planned Spark2, the reason is that proxy node has too many (20+) roles, I wonder if anyone can give any suggestion here? I checked Cloudera doc, I don't see a guideline on it (or maybe I missed it?)

Thanks lots.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a slight disagreement with the other answer, which says

> By default any host running a service will have the config files
>   included so you don't need to add a gateway role to your Node Manager
>   and Resource Manager roles

Just having Node Manager and Resource Manager running on a node will **only** give you the configuration files for YARN, not Spark2. That being said, you only need to deploy Spark gateway role to your edge node, where you allow end user to login and run command line tool such as beeline, hdfs command and spark-shell/spark-submit. No one should be allowed to login your Node Manager/Datanode, as a security policy.

In your case, it looks like what you call proxy node. The gateway is just configuration files and is not a running process. So I don't think you need to be concerned about too many existing roles.

Comment: yet when using oozie to run your jobs, you seem to need this gateway role. As without it, for instance, hive-site.xml will be missing and you get errors in your job.

Answer (score 1):

A gateway role just has the config files such as /etc/hadoop/conf/*.  It allows clients to run on that host (the hdfs, hadoop, yarn, spark CLIs) and submit commands to the cluster.  By default any host running a service will have the config files included so you don't need to add a gateway role to your Node Manager and Resource Manager roles.

The official documentation describes it as such:
[Managing Roles: Gateway Roles](https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-9-x/topics/cm_mc_managing_roles.html#xd_583c10bfdbd326ba-3ca24a24-13d80143249--7f3c__section_scv_ywt_cn)

> A gateway is a special type of role whose sole purpose is to designate a host that should receive a client configuration for a specific service, when the host does not have any roles running on it. Gateway roles enable Cloudera Manager to install and manage client configurations on that host. There is no process associated with a gateway role, and its status will always be Stopped. You can configure gateway roles for HBase, HDFS, Hive, Kafka, MapReduce, Solr, Spark, Sqoop 1 Client, and YARN.